# Разные ID у одного и того же опроса telegram

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бота который формирует опрос при добавлении новой информации в django модель и отправляет в определенную группу. Мне надо связать пользователя о котором формируется этот опрос и ID самого опроса что бы когда я получал информацию о том что кто то проголосовал я знал точно о каком опросе идет речь. Для этого использую словарь.

Проблема заключается в том что когда ID который я получаю в обработчике базы данных через poll.id и тот который я получаю в обработчике poll_answer_handler() через .poll_id выдают разный результат. Соответсвенно получаю ошибку словаря и chat_id = none а не нужное мне значение. Пробова делать так: poll_answer.poll.id но получал ошибку что у poll_answer нет такого атрибута как poll.

Объясните пожалуйста почему разные значения.

Вот код:

```
import telebot
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from servak.models import db, acceptedUserModel
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import os
from telebot.types import Poll, PollOption
myDict = {}



# Замените "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN" на ваш токен бота
def runBot2():
    bot2 = telebot.TeleBot("xxx")

    @receiver(post_save, sender=db)
    def send_message_on_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            group_chat_id = "-922328360"

        photo_file_path = instance.photoPath

        strArr = instance.clientCredintials_napr.split(' ')
        userName = strArr[0]
        userAge = strArr[1]
        userPhone = strArr[2]
        with open(photo_file_path, 'rb') as photo_file:
            bot2.send_photo(-922328360, photo_file,
                            caption=" Name: " + userName + "\n Age: " + userAge + "\n Instagram: " + userPhone)

            # Create poll options
            options = [PollOption("Принять", "1"), PollOption("Отклонить", "2")]

            # Create the poll
            poll = bot2.send_poll(-922328360, "Do you like this?", options, type="regular", correct_option_id=0, is_anonymous=False)
            myDict[poll.message_id] = instance.clientChat_id
            print (poll.id)

    @bot2.poll_answer_handler()
    def handle_poll_answer(poll_answer):
        voteFor = 0
        print(poll_answer.option_ids[0])
        for i in range (0, len(poll_answer.option_ids)):
            if (poll_answer.option_ids[i] == 0):
                voteFor+=1
        print (voteFor)
        if voteFor >= 1:
            print(poll_answer.poll_id)
            chat_id = myDict.get(poll_answer.poll_id)
            print ("chat_id: ", chat_id)
            if chat_id is not None:
                addToModelInfo = acceptedUserModel(clientChatId=chat_id)
                addToModelInfo.save()


    bot2.polling()
```